# Why PHP pack("h*", 0x41) function prints wrong ASCII text

Tags: php, hex, pack

I read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) how to use the `pack` function in PHP.

According to the documentation the `h` format will print

> Hex string, low nibble first

I wanted to check how it works so I ran the following command:

```
echo pack("h*", 0x41) . "<br />"  ;
```

You can try it on [this](http://www.writephponline.com/) online PHP commands website.

It prints the character `V`.
But `0x41` is `65` in decimal, `01000001` in binary and `A` in ASCII/ANSI.
Why it printed `V` and not `A` ?
I understand that it packs it in binary structure, but binary structure is `01000001` which should be `A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly, using the right format for `h`, **low** nibble first, so:

```
echo pack("h*", "14");
```

Output:

```
A
```

Same output for `H` with **high** nibble first:

```
echo pack("H*", "41");
```

It's better to use `H` for more intuitiveness.

Comment: Thanks. I probably didn't understand what is nibble so I will read more about it. I used `pack("h*", $var)` because I saw it in some code and tried to understand how it works.

Answer (score 1):

I think you use the wrong format,The format of pack introduce like this:

1. h : Hex string, low nibble first
2. c : signed char

So you try it like this:

```
echo pack("h*", 0x41) . "<br />"  ;
```

It prints the character V.

When you try it like this:

```
echo pack("c*", 0x41) . "<br />"  ;
```

It prints the character A.